# Delete earlier commits in Git

Tags: git

I want to delete a couple of earlier commits. This is what my repo looks like now -

```
R----A----B----C----HEAD.
```

I want to remove commits A and C and also discard changes made by them. This is how my repo should look like -

```
R----B-----HEAD.
```

How can I do this in Git?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use  `git rebase -i R`,  delete the `A` and `C` lines and save.

See [Interactive Rebasing](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) from Git Community Book and [reorder commits with rebase](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/20/reorder-commits-with-rebase.html) from git ready for details.

Comment: Be aware that this will rewrite your git history!

Comment: ... which is a problem if someone has cloned your repo

Comment: Thanks, decided not to do it after all. Will overwrite the changes.

Comment: @Pranav, `git revert` works well for undoing changes from specific commits without rewriting history.